# Add onclick function on html element with node playwright

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer, playwright

Im working with playwright and i need to inject an onclick function on an html element.

I have this example where i remove the element.

```
const elementHandle = await page.$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl_Val_Tomador');
await elementHandle.evaluate(node => node.remove());
```

So, which function do i need to run to inject the onclick on this element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$eval](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-eval-on-selector) like this:

```
await page.$eval('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl_Val_Tomador', node => { 
  node.onclick = () => console.log(1);
});
```

Comment: thanks! i also tried: 

node.onclick = () => window.location.href=url;

But it didnt work.

Comment: await page.$eval('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl_Val_Tomador', (node, url) => { 
  node.onclick = () => window.location.href=url;
}, \`https://playwright.dev/\`);